# asp.net MVC/WEB API - How to store authorization token

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-web-api

I am working on an ASP.NET MVC 4 app with WEB API. THe MVC client makes a call to WEB API for authorization and receives a token in return. Or another pre authorized brower might just pass the token to MVC client and this will not need re authorization from MVC client. I would like to store this token for further WEB API calls. And i dont want to store it in a cookie as well. Any pointers on how to achieve this will be helpful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `session token support`

With the session token support you could do it like this:

- Use an arbitrary supported credential (e.g. a password) to request a session token. The session token endpoint is built right into the authentication handler.
- The session token response contains the token itself and an expiration time.
- Afterwards throw away the bootstrap credential and store the token instead.
- When the token has expired, the user has to re-authenticate to obtain a new token. Then start over.

> This is very similar to e.g. the Google IDs long lived authentication
>   cookie. They establish an SSO session for a limited amount of time
>   (approx. 2 weeks), then you have to enter your password again.

For more information check this out [**Session Token Support for ASP.NET Web API**](http://leastprivilege.com/2012/06/19/session-token-support-for-asp-net-web-api/)

I hope this will help to you.